# Trouble setting Network Interface in CentOS rescue

Tags: centos

My hosting service has just provided my 2 IP addresses, gateway and a Nameserver but in CentOS's rescue mode, I need to enable networking which has prefix field also. I have no idea what to fill in ipv4 field after '/'. Please help me with this.

[image: error]

Comment: tried filling /24 which resulted an error

Comment: I'd take this up with your hosting provider as they should be able to easily help you out on this as without the specific information provided I would not be able to help. (could be subnetted, etc....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually setting an IP is done with a command like `ifconfig eth0 10.1.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0` or `ip addr add dev eth0 10.1.1.1/24` depending on if you want to use ifconfig or iproute2.

The prefix you received is translated into the netmask value.

Comment: having a look at screenshot 'll give you idea about where I am stuck at.

http://i.imgur.com/4Ox6S.png

Comment: You put in your netmask.  If it is `255.255.255.0` then you put in `24`.  If the netmask is something else you can easily find a subnet calculator to help.

Comment: My netmask is `255.255.255.0` and I am filling in `24` only but it is still not working.

Comment: Be more specific.  What exactly do you mean by not working.  Do you get an error from the input box, or does the network not work?

Comment: I am getting error after inputting these details that the details that I am unable to set up network interface eth0

Comment: There was an error configuring network device eth0

Comment: Worked like a charm!